# How to redirect or handle old URL in simple way when I change website from WordPress to Laravel web?

Tags: php, laravel

I have changed my website from WordPress to Laravel framework but I want to hold my traffic when visit through old URL. How can redirect those visitors to new urls in simple way? I don't have much experience in code and command line.

Comment: Take a look at the Laravel Documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#redirect-routes

Simply go over to your `web.php` file and declare a route redirection:
`Route::redirect('/old-url', '/new-url');`

Provided you use the same domain of course.

Comment: Thanks much, then after nothing to do in WordPress rather than delete everything and start using Laravel version.

Comment: Unfortunately this not working for the old WordPress pages, is there more addition code required?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you need to redirect from old URL to new URL, you essentially say that you intend to leave your Wordpress site where it was and to ensure that the server redirects to a new URL. I will ignore the "simple way" part, as programming is considered anything but simple, but, in PHP you can redirect to a new URL via:

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

however, you should think this through, because you have the option of setting up your new, Laravel version on the server where the old, Wordpress version is hosted. That would completely render your redirect task unnecessary and would probably be better financially, assuming that you need to pay for your Wordpress hosting as well.